# CodeIgniter: Trying to load the option values from database table based on the selection of first select option

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter and have a form with 2 select options. First select options is the Car Make and the second select option is the Make. If I select the Car Make from the As 'BMW' the Values in the second select options should change and show all the Models Made by BMW.

```
**WelcometoDemoCar.php (View)**

*//to get the Car Make List Box*

<input type = "text" name = "car_list" list="car_dalalist" id = "car_list" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Type of Car" required = "" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="car_dalalist">
 <?php foreach($carlist as $row_carlist){?>
<?php //echo $row_carlist->Make . " " .$row_carlist->Model ." " .$row_carlist->Year ;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_carlist->Make;?>"> <?php echo $row_carlist->Make;?></option>
<?php }?> 
</datalist>


*//to get the value in the Make Select List Box*


<input type = "text" name = "car_model" list="car_model_dalalist" id = "car_model" class = "inktext inklarge" placeholder = "Car Model" required = <datalist id="car_model_dalalist">
<?php foreach($carModel as $row_carModel){?>
<?php //echo $row_carlist->Make . " " .$row_carlist->Model ." " .$row_carlist->Year ;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row_carModel->Model;?>"><?php echo $row_carModel->Model;?> </option>
<?php }?> 
</datalist> 


**Welcome.php (Controller)**

$this->data['carlist'] = $this->PostModel->getCarDetails(); 
$this->data['carModel'] = $this->PostModel->getCarModel();

**PostModel.php (Model)**



*//to get car make*

 function getCarDetails(){
  $this->db->Distinct();
  $this->db->select("Make"); 
  $this->db->from('carlist');
  $carListquery = $this->db->get();
  return $carListquery->result();
 }


 *// to get car model*


 function getCarModel(){
  $make = $this->input->post('car_list');   

  $this->db->Distinct();
  $this->db->select("Model"); 
  $this->db->from('carlist');
  $this->db->where('Make' . $make);
  $carmodelquery = $this->db->get();
  return $carmodelquery->result();
 }


public function get_data()
 {
      $value = $this->input->post("value");
      $data = $this->PostModel->get_data($value);
      $option ="";
      foreach($data as $d)
      {
         $option .= "<option value='".$d->id."' >".$d->Model."</option>";
      }
       echo $option;
 }
```

I tried few solutions posted on various sites  using ajax, but I think my values are not getting posted to the controller.

ajax code

```
    $("#car_list").on("change",function(){ 
    var value = $(this).val(); 
    $.ajax({ url : "welcome/get_data", 
    type: "post", 
    data: {"value":'value'}, 

    success : function(data){ 
    $("#car_model").html(data); 
    }, 
   });
  });
```

Really appreciate your time and help.

Thank in advance.

Comment: @can you please share your ajax code

Comment: @Abhijit i have updated my ajax code

Comment: this "#car_list" not present in form. also get_data() is not present in the code you provided

Comment: @Abhijit sorry my bad.. the element name and ID is car_list. Its same in the model and controller as car_list. I will update now my code

Comment: @Abhijit i have just updated my code in the question. Sorry!!

Comment: @Abhijit I have just updated the get_data()

Comment: @SarahMalik in your ajax you are calling `welcome/get_data` can you provide this function in the welcome controller? (i.e. if you have it , if you don't then that is the issue)

Comment: i have created the get_data function inside the welcome controller. but i think, the ajax is not able to access this URL. I am not too sure, just guessing

Comment: How can I check if this URL is accessible from the ajax. Sorry, this is my ever first MVC and Codeignter project.

Comment: @SarahMalik ah, i see ... have you set your base_url? if so you can try to do something like this-----------         `url : <?php echo base_url(); ?>Welcome/get_data'` for the ajax url ... It is important to know that at least the view is seeing the controller. maybe you can echo something from the controller and immediately return in the the view to see if it at least sees it

Comment: I tried to access the URl and able to load the page with the error, showing there is a for each `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: @SarahMalik you accessed it the controller from the browser? that is not going to work because it is expecting `post` request. also in your question: the `get_data` function is under **model** ... is this correct? if so where is the `get_data` for the **controller**. It is easier to help you if we can reproduce/simulate the issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178511/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-emineminems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues regarding the code. 
For future reference: see the comments on the OP's post

Main issue was with the click handler:

```
    $("#car_list").on("change",function(){ 
     var value = $(this).val(); 
     $.ajax({ url : "welcome/get_data", 
     type: "post", 
     data: {"value":value}, //OP originally used single quotes on the value therefore passing a string instead of the actualy variable

     success : function(data){ 
     $("#car_model").html(data); 
     }, 
     });
     });
```

Issues with the controller and model

```
 public function get_data()
 {
      $data = $this->PostModel->get_data(); //OP originally passed $value to the model but $value does not exist
      $option ="";

      if(count($data) > 0){
          foreach($data as $d)
          {
             $option .= "<option value='".$d->Model."' >".$d->Model."</option>";
          }
          echo $option;
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update `data: {"value":'value'},`  with `data: {"value":value}` 
( Remove single quotes from value )

Comment: I change it to car_list from value, but still not is showing up in the dropdown list.

Comment: Can you see the AJAX call being triggered and what value is posted for it in request?